# Restrict the fields that Lucene returns

Tags: json, lucene

Can I restrict the fields that Lucene.net (v2) returns when running a search?  I am looking for the most efficient way to return a json-formatted response to the client where I only want a subset of the stored fields included in the response.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java version you can specify an optional `FieldSelector` when calling `IndexReader.document(...)`.

See the [JavaDoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldSelector.html).